# Display Nested ListViews (Menus to Submenus) with AccessDataSource

Tags: asp.net, listview, datasource

Good Days,

By using ASP.NET and AccessDataSource, I need to display a listview inside a parent listview to be able to have menus and their submenus. Current state of my code is:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="adsMenus" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/menus.accdb" SelectCommand="SELECT MenuID, Menu FROM Menus" />

<asp:ListView ID="lvwMenus" runat="server" DataSourceID="adsMenus" DataKeyNames="MenuID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2><%#Eval("Menu")%></h2>

        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="adsSubmenus" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/menus.accdb" SelectCommand="SELECT Submenu FROM Submenus WHERE MenuID = <%#Eval('MenuID')%>" />

        <asp:ListView ID="lvwSubmenus" runat="server" DataSourceID="adsSubmenus">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h3><%#Eval("Submenu")%></h3>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView> 

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

When I debug and run the page, it gives a syntax error. I am in the phase of learning ASP.NET with C# and I believe this should be an easy fix but somehow I couldn't find a simple solution after reading several blogs and posts.

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute that has a value formed from literals and evaluated fields should be, as a rule, constructued wholly in the `<%# %>`:

```
SelectCommand='<%# string.Format("SELECT Submenu FROM Submenus WHERE MenuID = {0}", Eval("MenuID")) %>'
```

Comment: <asp:AccessDataSource ID="adsSubmenus" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/menus.accdb" SelectCommand='<%# string.Format("SELECT Submenu FROM Submenus WHERE MenuID = {0}", Eval("MenuID")) #>' /> This time it gives "The server tag is not well formed" error.

Comment: @User3656597, sorry, my bad, it should be `%>`, not `#>`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Andrei.